# replace command not working with empty string

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to replace an empty string in BigQuery with a '0'. I can't get it to work nohow.

```
create temp table doodle_ns
  (col_with_ns string)
;

insert doodle_ns select '';


select replace(col_with_ns, '', '0')
from doodle_ns;
```

Result set shows a blank value:

Comment: You cannot replace a `nothing value` as it does not exist. Try filling your value with something like `'null'` and then it should work.

Comment: This changed the value to null (rather than 'null).

select replace(col_with_ns, '', null)
from doodle_ns;

That would seem to refute what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, read comment by Jeremy
Meantime, I feel what you really want is something like below

```
select * replace (
  if(col_with_ns = '', '0', col_with_ns) as col_with_ns
)
from doodle_ns
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny, cause this does work...

select regexp_replace(col_with_ns, '', '0')
from doodle_ns;

I wonder if this is actually a bug.

Comment: try against any non empty string! for example for `12` it returns `01020` which most likely is not OP's intention. the point is - empty string does not have empty char, while technically non-empty string has all chars separated by empty char :o)